# Flutter equivalent to UISearchBar with UISegmentControl

Tags: flutter, searchbar

I need to implement a SearchBar like the UISearchBar + SegmentedControl.
SegmentedControl attach to UISearchBar allow to do filtering in addition to the TextField Search capabilities.

How to do the same kind of widget in Flutter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Material like this just by using the [showSearch](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/showSearch.html) function, in this [Video](https://youtu.be/Wm3OiFBZ2xI) by the flutter Team you will learn how to implement your search 
[image]

Comment: I have checked the video but I do not see equivalent of the segmented control linked to the UISearchBar . I need something like that: https://dribbble.com/shots/2484657-Filter-search-by-state

Comment: It look like `TabBar` to me